# How to internatialize all projects under suite project

Tags: java, netbeans, internationalization

I want to set localization parameters for all module projects under suite module project. 
For single project I can use VM options like -Duser.language=es -Duser.country=ES.
How can I set up this parameter for suite module project instead of every project.
Thanks!

Comment: I have found the solution. In the  platform.properties file I have added parameter run.args.extra=--locale xx:XX

Comment: then answer your question and accept and close it :)